# Let's get critical: Jan 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Philosophy Stack Exchange](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [A contradiction in Kant's Universalizability Principle](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8655/a-contradiction-in-kants-universalizability-principle)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is correlationism Kantian or post-Kantian?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8830/is-correlationism-kantian-or-post-kantian)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Why could Wittgenstein say that men had an idea for the law of least action?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8798/why-could-wittgenstein-say-that-men-had-an-idea-for-the-law-of-least-action)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Is there such a thing as provability of provability?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8703/is-there-such-a-thing-as-provability-of-provability)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Does Gödel's second incompleteness theorem interact with logical positivism?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8906/does-godels-second-incompleteness-theorem-interact-with-logical-positivism)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Do experiences need to be "real" to be worthwhile or desireable?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8629/do-experiences-need-to-be-real-to-be-worthwhile-or-desireable)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How to correctly pronounce the major philosophers names?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/how-to-correctly-pronounce-the-major-philosophers-names)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [As far as Marx was concerned, is all of history predestined, including human actions?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8904/as-far-as-marx-was-concerned-is-all-of-history-predestined-including-human-act)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Truth for logicians, mathematicians, and philosophers](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8858/truth-for-logicians-mathematicians-and-philosophers)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [best Phaedrus edition to start with for beginner](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/best-phaedrus-edition-to-start-with-for-beginner)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

Answer (score 2):

(I asked "pronounce major philosophers names?" lol)

Here is a personal anecdote from my first days viewing the site: I thought it was too strict with the rules imposed on questions. At the time, I did not know about Quora.com, and thought it was wrong to eliminate the possibility of answering a question--from someone who *did* have the credibility. I came to understand the site through my questions, and the comments to their answers. It seems politeness and referencing the Meta are what convinced me from stereotyping the whole site as stuck up.

In a nutshell, if it was not for the polite comments referencing the Meta by Weissman and Stoicfurry, I would have almost dismissed the site as caught in a format (general guidelines) that really limited, maybe, Truth. (Hope you got a chance to slip into my shoes.)

In general, I widely use Google Adv Search. Much of the ideas, sometimes even the resources, in my philosophy essays come from the questions, answers and comments of the site. I mean, the usefulness of a good number of these inquires are better than the comments to articles (which are usually more insightful than the article alone) in an accelerated or purified way.

As for what's mentioned in the beginning of this Q, this is a similar idea being discussed on [this Academia Stack](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/publicizing-the-site). Also, I had [this](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134/publicity-poster) in my AcademiaMeta favorites. Furthermore, is there a short 1-3m video out there about any Stack Exchange? If not, *someone* should try on Vimeo.

Maybe a video of two people in suits. One is in a Stack Exchange type mascot suit; one in a Quora suit. And then--a battle to the death! Some food for thought.

Comment: Thank you for you insight, it is useful, and I agree with many of your points. The rules here do limit philosophy in ways that is harder for people to accept as opposed to sites like stackoverflow or math. Do I think the format works? Yes, I think the format works for what it is supposed to do: create a knowledgebase of specific questions and factual answers without the excessive rambling of unsourced, wildly irrelevant side chatter. Other philosophy sites (e.g., open forums), you have random people posting random comments and it drowns out the expertise. The voting system here allows (cont.)

Comment: the best, most factual answers to shine through. The thing you *can't* do here, however, and I think what most newcomers hope to do, is have someone focus their jumbled thought processes on a particular topic. They want to start a discussion and browse people's ideas ("doing philosophy"). This you *can* do, but not on the main site — we push that stuff to chat, but I agree chat is not the best place. What would be ideal is if there was a way to flag your question as discussion and have it be separated from the main site unless each user enabled a filter or setting somewhere (opt-in by choice).

Answer (score 1):

My notes:

- [best Phaedrus edition to start with for beginner](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/best-phaedrus-edition-to-start-with-for-beginner)

  A prototypical [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).  That's not necessarily a bad thing, but this is not a great example.  I enjoyed a [different Hackett-published translation](http://www.hackettpublishing.com/complete-works), but I don't konw if the recommendation will clear or muddy the waters because I don't know what matters to the asker.
- [Truth for logicians, mathematicians, and philosophers](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8858/truth-for-logicians-mathematicians-and-philosophers)

  Yikes.  I can't even start to figure out how to look for this question since it's a double-barrel shotgun's worth.  Might be good encourage askers to focus.  There seems to be good material in the answers, but they deserve a better question.
- [As far as Marx was concerned, is all of history predestined, including human actions?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8904/as-far-as-marx-was-concerned-is-all-of-history-predestined-including-human-act)

  Another unfocused question.  The answer is helpful however.  If you are interested in how Marx and Newton might have conversed about determinism, [Google points to this question](https://www.google.com/search?q=marx+newton+determinism).  However, I think Newton is largely a red herring; this is a question about Marx.
- [How to correctly pronounce the major philosophers names?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/how-to-correctly-pronounce-the-major-philosophers-names)

  A strangely popular question.  I'd love to see an answer reference [this oddity](http://www.critical-theory.com/a-competely-incorrect-guide-to-pronouncing-philosophers/), but sadly everyone plays it straight.

  I'm going to suggest that text Q&A is the wrong format for this question.  That doesn't make it invalid; just a misfire.  Even so, the answer is fine and helpful.
- [Do experiences need to be "real" to be worthwhile or desireable?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8629/do-experiences-need-to-be-real-to-be-worthwhile-or-desireable)

  A nice meaty question with a number of stabs at an answer.  Best question on the evaluation so far. (That shouldn't surprise; I'm working from the worst to the best evaluation.)  But the accepted answer is... not an answer.  None of the answers satisfies because none brings any philosophers to bear on the question.  (Not that it's a requirement; it just would give me more confidence in the answers.)
- [Does Gödel's second incompleteness theorem interact with logical positivism?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8906/does-godels-second-incompleteness-theorem-interact-with-logical-positivism)

  As phrased, the question and answer read as a sort of extended dialog between the asker and answerer.  That's ok, I suppose, but it tends be a little inaccessible to outsiders.  Google tends to point to an more readable question and answer: [Should Wittgenstein be given some credit for Godel's incompleteness theorem?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1028/should-wittgenstein-be-given-some-credit-for-godels-incompleteness-theorem) That answer is not as full as I might like, but of the two, I prefer the question about Wittgenstein's role.
- [Is there such a thing as provability of provability?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8703/is-there-such-a-thing-as-provability-of-provability)

  The update muddles the question a touch, but the answer is useful and clear.  Search results turned up some dictionary definitions, some math sites (MathOverflow and Math.SE, in fact), the SEP article ["Provability Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-provability/), and this question.  This is very close to an Excellent result in my book.
- [Why could Wittgenstein say that men had an idea for the law of least action?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8798/why-could-wittgenstein-say-that-men-had-an-idea-for-the-law-of-least-action)

  Interesting question that gets a top spot in my Google search.  The answer is thought-provoking, but the comments probably need to be incorporated into the answer somehow.  Again, I'd like some references to working philosophers here.  Just shy of Excellent.
- [Is correlationism Kantian or post-Kantian?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8830/is-correlationism-kantian-or-post-kantian)

  To start, I don't "get" Kant.  His work leaves me cold and I feel like either he or I miss the point the subject he writes about.  So this question and its answer fail to engage me at all.  I *can* say that they turn up reasonably well in Google searches however.  Since both asker and answerer seem satisfied with the result, this is an Excellent result.
- [A contradiction in Kant's Universalizability Principle](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8655/a-contradiction-in-kants-universalizability-principle)

  More Kant, a very searchable question, and an answer that makes sense even to me.  Excellent in almost every respect.  My one nitpick is that if the question didn't really need to show any more work after "eating a potato is wrong."

### Summary

I think this evaluation is spot on; most of the questions need some work.  I've long thought that this is the hardest site on the network to ask a good question, so it would be good if more people assisted askers via comments and edits.  Good answers will, of course, correct simple misunderstandings.  But overly broad and vague questions need to be closed, fixed, and reopened.  It's work that is often unrewarded, but it's often necessary.